# Airflow Not triggering sla_miss_callback for my case

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I have followed the documentation and previous stackoverflow links eg : [Airflow sla_miss_callback function not triggering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59959290/airflow-sla-miss-callback-function-not-triggering)
Still I am not able to trigger `sla_miss_callback` for my case.

I have a top level DAG(DAG X1) that has scheduler interval of : `0 18 * * *` -> run everyday at 6 pm.
This calls sub DAG(DAG Y1) using `TriggerDagRunOperator`.
Sub DAG Y1 do not have schedule interval attached so I cannot apply SLA to it because of this piece of code - [Airflow Code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1394b1a986bf63f6910eaaf7b5d92f24f2623ff4/airflow/dag_processing/processor.py#L418)

So I have attached SLA to my top level DAG task exactly the same way as this - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.1/concepts/tasks.html#slas

```
@dag(
    schedule_interval="0 18 * * *",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    sla_miss_callback=sla_callback,
    default_args={'sla': timedelta(seconds=60)
}

def sla_callback(dag, task_list, blocking_task_list, slas, blocking_tis):
    print(
        "The callback arguments are: ",
        {
            "dag": dag,
            "task_list": task_list,
            "blocking_task_list": blocking_task_list,
            "slas": slas,
            "blocking_tis": blocking_tis,
        },
    )
```

In my DAG Processor log I do see this log
 `{{processor.py:377}} INFO - Running SLA Checks for DAG X1`, Coming from this part of the [Airflow Code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/dag_processing/processor.py#L370)
but after that I dont see any log related to SLA and SLA Callback function is not getting kicked off. My DAG run time is more than hour long.

Comment: What is the configuration for logging for the DagProcessor?

Comment: We are facing the same issue here, we found that our `DAGFileProcessorProcess` is being killed by the processor. We think this might be the case, because the callback is made inside of the processor. Will keep you updated.

Comment: We found the logs of the slas on `/airflow/logs/scheduler/latest/workflow/dags` that for some reason doesn't go to the logs in the web. That is where we could find the details why our `sla_callbacks` are not working.